# Почему не отрабатывает фильтр?(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть дропдаун, в котором пользователь выбирает определенную позицию(при этом выбирается айди). Также есть контейнеры, которые имеют атрибут data-filter, который в зависимости от категории тоже имеют id.Имеем дропдаун:

```
<select class="filter">
<option value=1>Name 1</option>
<option value=2>Name 2</option>
<option value=3>Name 3</option>
</select>
```

Один из контейнеров,которые нужно фильтрвоать по атрибуту data-filter:

```
<div class="item" data-filter=2>container</div>
```

Таких контейнеров много. Я попробовал взять по селектору .item пробежаться циклом each()  и в нем поставить условие при котором контейнеры будут .hide() или .show().Это оказалось накладно с точки зрения производительности.Тогда я обратился к функции filter().

```
var valuee = $(this).val(); // тут извлекаем значение дропдауна,который выбрал пользователь
        $('.item').filter(function(index){
            return $( this ).data( "filter" ) === valuee;
        });
```

Не работает. Судя по всему проблема в методе filter(),но я не догоняю в чем именно.Как можно перепесать эту функцию,чтобы она работала?

Comment: Ваш случай - один из достаточно редких случаев, когда Вы можете полностью воспроизвести проблему в Вашем вопросе, используя кнопку редактора "Фрагмент кода на ...", чтобы облегчить задачу человеку, который захочет Вам помочь. Вместо этого Вы включили в Ваш вопрос неработающие обрывки html и javascript'а, предоставив нам гадать, насколько полно они отражают действительное положение вещей.

Comment: Конкретно к Вашей проблеме (исходя из приведенного кода): `$().filter` - не прячет/показывает элементы DOM, а возвращает объект-обертку вокруг выборки элементов. `$('.item').filter(...).hide();`

Comment: Вы правы-добавление .hide(); в конце позволяет спрятать ненужные элементы. благодаря пояснению про обертку понял, в чем мой недочет. спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Метод `filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) - **возвращает** отфильтрованную коллекцию. С самими элементами при этом ничего не происходит.

Поэтому вызов

```
$('.item').filter(function(index){
    return $( this ).data( "filter" ) === valuee;
});
```

Вернул нужные элементы, но так как с полученной коллекцией не производятся никакие действия, соответственно нет и результата.

Answer (score 2):

У вас ошибка тут:

```
return $(this).data("filter") === valuee;
```

Нужно так:

```
return $( this ).data( "filter" ) == valuee;
```

Т.к. `$(this).val();` вернет строку а `$(this).data("filter")` число.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/w89zerff/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Поэкспериментировав, методом тыка получил нужный результат, когда прикрутил метод .css() к методу filter().Оно работае,но все равно я до конца не понимаю как и думаю есть еще какие-то решения без прикручивания inline-стилей. Готов выслушать любые комментарии и предложения)

```
var valuee = parseInt($(this).val());
    $('.item').filter(function () {
        return $(this).data("filter") != valuee;
    }).css({'display': 'none'});
```